# Mapping select query to an object makes an error in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class like this:

```
public class studentpres
{
  public string stuname { set; get; }
  public  string stlastaname { set; get; }
  public string stunumber { set; get; }
  public string stumajor { set; get; }
  public string stufiled { set; get; }
  public string stuaverage { set; get; }
  public string stumobile { set; get; }
  public string stuemail { set; get; }
  public string stuprofSupervisor { set; get; }
  public string prifsuperEmail { set; get; }
}
```

I make a query like this :

```
public studentpres Get_Student_List(string stuNumber)
{
    studentpres temp =
        from i in dbconnect.tblUsers
        join d in dbconnect.tblNovitiates
            on i.tblStudent.studentNumber equals d.studentNumber
        select new PresentClass.studentpres()
        {
            prifsuperEmail = d.profSupervisorUSername,
            stlastaname = i.family,
            stuaverage = i.tblStudent.average,
            stuemail = i.email,
            stufiled = i.tblStudent.field,
            stumajor = i.tblStudent.major,
            stumobile = i.mobile,
            stuname = i.name,
            stunumber = i.tblStudent.studentNumber,
            stuprofSupervisor = Return_Name_By_userName(d.profSupervisorUSername)
        };
}
```

But i got this error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<Novitiate.AdminPortal.PresentationClass.PresentClass.studentpres>'`
>   to
>   `'Novitiate.AdminPortal.PresentationClass.PresentClass.studentpres'`.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I also added a **Tolist()** to the end of the query but it didn't work again;
Thanks

Comment: Try using `var temp` instead of using the studentpres type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns `IQueryable<studentpres>` result but you are trying to assign it to variable of `studentpres` type. If you are expecting many results, then change return type of your method (from method name I assume you need to do this) to `IQueryable<studentpres>` or `IEnumerable<studentpres>`:

```
public IQueryable<studentpres> Get_Student_List(string stuNumber)
{
    return from i in dbconnect.tblUsers
           join d in dbconnect.tblNovitiates 
                    on i.tblStudent.studentNumber equals d.studentNumber
           select new PresentClass.studentpres()
           {
               prifsuperEmail = d.profSupervisorUSername,
               stlastaname = i.family,
                   // ...
           };
}
```

Note - `IQueryable<studentpress>` will return query instead of result of query execution. If you want to get query results, then you should execute it (i.e. save query results to list):

```
public IList<studentpres> Get_Student_List(string stuNumber)
{
    var query = from i in dbconnect.tblUsers
                join d in dbconnect.tblNovitiates 
                    on i.tblStudent.studentNumber equals d.studentNumber
                select new PresentClass.studentpres()
                {
                   prifsuperEmail = d.profSupervisorUSername,
                   stlastaname = i.family,
                   stuaverage = i.tblStudent.average,
                   stuemail = i.email,
                   stufiled = i.tblStudent.field,
                   stumajor = i.tblStudent.major,
                   stumobile = i.mobile,
                   stuname = i.name,
                   stunumber = i.tblStudent.studentNumber,
                   stuprofSupervisor = 
                      Return_Name_By_userName(d.profSupervisorUSername)
                };

      return query.ToList(); // executes query
}
```

---

If you want to get single result, then call `FistOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` on query:

```
public studentpres Get_Student_List(string stuNumber)
{
    var query = from i in dbconnect.tblUsers
                join d in dbconnect.tblNovitiates 
                    on i.tblStudent.studentNumber equals d.studentNumber
                select new PresentClass.studentpres()
                {
                   prifsuperEmail = d.profSupervisorUSername,
                   stlastaname = i.family,
                   // ...
                };

    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you .i found my error basically by your explanation

Answer (score 3):

Your query returns `IQueryable<studentpres>`, you should select only one record, use: `Single`, `First` or other methods:

1. Single
2. SingleOrDefault
3. First
4. FirstOrDefault